# Virtual Box freezes when guest operating is restarting or shut down

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box version 4.2.4 which is installed on Windows XP SP3

I have installed Oracle Linux on virtual box and when I shutdown or re-start linux, I get the following
and it freezes at this point.

```
virtualbox ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:00:11.0 disabled
```

I have not enabled 3D acceleration and once I made preview in virtual box as 
**Update Disabled** guest installation got lost and I had to re-install guest additions.

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is highly appreciable

Comment: Do you shutdown VM via Host+H ?

Comment: @inhabitant When I shutdown or restart guest OS which is Oracle Linux, virtual box and guest OS hangs or freezes during the restart or shutdown when it reaches at this point. `virtualbox ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:00:11.0 disabled`. Regards

Comment: You need to check whether ACPI shutdown is enabled in Oracle Linux, if Not - it should be enabled.
Perhaps, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82015/shutting-down-ubuntu-server-running-in-headless-virtualbox) article will help you.

Comment: @inhabitant I will check this. I have a question though, I do shutdown or restart from guest OS and do I still need to enable APCI? Regards

Comment: Make sure it's not trying to deal with a CD-ROM it can't find. See http://askubuntu.com/a/410497/351869

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by enabling IO APIC in Virtual Box.

Courtesy [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=52581)

Regards